# AngularJS communication between nested directives with transclusion

Tags: angularjs

I have created a DSL for a "step-by-step" mobile wizard. A `<wizard>` contains one or more `<wz-section>` which contain one or more `<wz-step>`.

Each `<wz-step>` contains a `<wz-input-xyz>` directive which renders a specific input field for each complex type (text, boolean radio choice, REST sourced listview with checkboxes, etc...).

The `<wz-step>` directive has its own isolated scope, and sets `$scope.selected = true` when the wizard flow arrives to that step.

I don't know how to create a set of different `<wz-input-xyz>` directives which `require: [^wzStep]` and can read some scope variables from the parent `<wz-step>` (eg: show a readonly text or an `<input>` control) and trigger events on it (eg: `onFieldFilled()`, to let the wizard to move to the next step or section).

This is the main controller template:

```
<wizard id="mainWizard">
<wz-section id="myProfile" title="My Profile">
    <wz-step id="firstName" title="First Name">
        <wz-input-text model="submission.persons[0].FirstName"></wz-input-text>
    </wz-step>
    <wz-step id="lastName" title="Last Name">
        <wz-input-text model="submission.persons[0].LastName"></wz-input-text>
    </wz-step>
</wz-section>
<wz-section id="myTreasure" title="My Treasure">
    <wz-step id="treasureMake" title="Treasure Make">
        <wz-input-text model="submission.treasures[0].Make"></wz-input-text>
    </wz-step>
    <wz-step id="treasureModel" title="Treasure Model">
        <wz-input-text model="submission.treasures[0].Model"></wz-input-text>
    </wz-step>
    <wz-step id="enableAdditionalFooBar" title="Do you need additional foobar?">
        <wz-input-radio-boolean model="wizardState.enableAdditionalFooBar" label-true="Yes, please" label-false="No, thanks"></wz-input-radio-boolean>
    </wz-step>
</wz-section>
</wizard>
```

I have prepared a JsFiddle to test the current implementation (try expanding the first section, select the text input and press enter key, you should see the wizard moving to the next step/section): http://jsfiddle.net/gcacace/c178g34n/2/

Comment: use the parent's controller to read these variables from the parent directive etc.

Comment: Move logic to services.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `$scope` events could help you tremendously here. I've built a similar system myself before, and used `$scope.$broadcast` from the parent to tell the children to close, and `$scope.$emit` from the child, to let the parent know that the input has been "satisfied".

[Angular $scope docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

You may also want to look at using `controllerAs` on your directives to expose a parent's api to it's children in the DOM.

Comment: I tried using `$scope.$broadcast` but it doesn't work, nested scopes are siblings (because of the default transclusion behaviour). How `controllerAs` should be used to help the communication between `<wz-input-xyz` and `<wz-field>`?